# How to change the default resolution of a web site in code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, resolution

I want to change my websites default resolution(you can press ctrl+0 key to see).
This is my site http://student.atilim.edu.tr/~tuncel.manil/ and its default resolution is too small.Zooming method does not worked in all browsers,the default resolution must change.I'd be appreciated if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a css for your website text
like

font-size: 1.3em;

This will increase your text size by realsize + 0.3% more

Answer (score 0):

change your font sizes in style.css. Also change the margin, padding, height, width of the components.

Comment: but I don't want to change all of them one by one.Isn't there a way to change all of them in one step?

Comment: you can use some GUI tools like dreamweaver, frontpage etc.

Comment: Thanks it worked.Note:Tables,menus,divs must be flexible in order to work this.